# Feature For Multiple OS

Tags: tycho

I want to create a feature for the basic Eclipse platform used to create our applications, but for multiple operating systems.

Since the *feature.xml* seems to support it, I thought as was easy as doing something like this:

```xml
<plugin
     id="org.eclipse.swt"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     unpack="false"/>
<plugin
     id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86"
     os="win32"
     ws="win32"
     arch="x86"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     fragment="true"
     unpack="false"/>
<plugin
     id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64"
     os="win32"
     ws="win32"
     arch="x86_64"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="0.0.0"
     fragment="true"
     unpack="false"/>
```

...adding the plug-ins into a target platform and building it using Tycho. However I get the following exception:

```
 [ERROR] Cannot resolve target definition:
 [ERROR]   Problems resolving provisioning plan.:
 [ERROR]      org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 3.7.2.v3740f cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition C:\workspaces\MyGreatWorkspace\org.acme.platform.feature\build.target: See log for details: org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 3.7.2.v3740f cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable. -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Neither the target platform definition nor the *pom.xml* have defined the `environment` tag, so I'm not even sure what Tycho is validating against.

Having the environment tag doesn't change the exception either:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- [SNIP] -->
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
```

How do I create a feature for multiple operating systems?